# Use start? method from opal-browser

Tags: javascript, ruby, opalrb

I am trying to translate this js code into ruby code

`document.ontouchstart ? 'touchstart' : 'click';`

I am using opal-browser to get browser functionality. My current attempt is this:

`touch = Browser::Event::Touch.new`
`puts touch.start?`

However this returns the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

When I checked the error trace the error seems to be coming from a missing name property in the Touch class.

Hoping Opal community can help me out here

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if touch is supported you need to call `Event::Touch.supported?`.

For the error, it's happening because `.new` expects the event object as parameter, if you want to create a new event object you need to call `.construct`.

In retrospect it would have probably been better to have `.construct` be `.new`, and `.new` be `.wrap` or something on that line.

Comment: Thanks! I had to do Browser::Event::touch.supported? but it totally worked